# VLCKit-based app prevents screensaver

Tags: macos, cocoa, vlc, libvlc, nsnotifications

I've recently built a simple Swift macOS app based upon VLCKit; its purpose is mainly to play IP camera streams via RTSP in a window that stays always visible on screen (i.e. to monitor a gate).

Given the purpose of the app, I keep the streaming playing all the time, except when the user minimizes it in the Dock (meaning that I only call mediaPlayer?.stop in viewDidDisappear).

The app works very well, but I've recently discovered that, **unless it is minimized (and, as a consequence, the playback is already stopped), something prevents the screensaver from running**.

I've tried subscribing to all NSNotificationCenter *com.apple.screensaver*.* notifications, and I've realized that when the playback is running, none of them is fired; **if I minimize the app and stop the playback, everything behaves normally (screensaver starts after the regular delay, all the com.apple.screensaver notifications are properly detected).**

I've also tried running *pmset -g* to check if my app was listed as preventing sleep, but it's not.

**My impression, but I might be wrong, is that my instance of VLCMediaPlayer by default prevents the screensaver launch.**

I know that in the VLC Mac app the screensaver can be manually prevented via an advanced setting, but I can't seem to be able to find a parameter to set in my code to tell VLCKit to stop blocking the screensaver.

**To your knowledge, by default VLCKit prevents the screensaver from running? Is there a way to alter that behavior?**

Please let me know if you need any further detail... and thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turned out VLCKit does actually prevent the screensaver from running by default, and that it doesn't use libvlc to do so, so the libvlc option "--no-disable-screensaver" I was at one point trying to pass was not respected.

**The solution was to comment out a UpdateSystemActivity() function call on line 1409 of VLCMediaPlayer.m**, as suggested to me [here](https://code.videolan.org/videolan/VLCKit/issues/159#note_12950).

Answer (score 1):

In VLC, there are options called "--disable-screensaver" and "--no-disable-screensaver". By default, "--disable-screensaver" is used.

If you want to enable screensaver just do this:

```
NSArray *options = @[@"--no-disable-screensaver"];
_mediaPlayer1 = [[VLCMediaPlayer alloc] initWithOptions:options];
```

What else options available in your VLC lib? pass option "--help" to your VLC and it will list all available options.

What is the full list of options? https://wiki.videolan.org/VLC_command-line_help/

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. It clearly should be the right one, because it explains how to pass exactly the parameter I should need via a custom initializer, something I didn't figure out. Strangely, though, passing this parameter does not change the behavior of my app, the screensaver does not start even when I pass that parameter. I'll dig more into it and check if I'm not causing the issue elsewhere. I'll wait just a few days before accepting it while I figure this out, but again, I believe your answer makes completely sense.

Comment: It should be OK as I got this options from the link above :] If it is not working, then we need to fire bug to VLC team!

Comment: Some options definitely work, for instance if I pass "--no-video", it stays black; others, such as "--grayscale" and "--disable-screensaver" seem to be ignored. It's actually pretty odd.

Comment: Have you tried pass "--help" to your VLC lib? Can you see "--disable-screensaver" in the list? If not, it may not work, VLC will ignore it.

Comment: boom! You're exactly right, "--disable-screensaver" is not listed in the console when I pass the "--help" parameter. So, back to square one :( Thanks again for all your help!

Comment: Try to build your own lib! I think the core vlc has that option for sure.

Comment: Turns out that, only on macOS, the library is ignoring the parameter passed to libvlc and handling the screensaver management directly, as it has been explained to me [here](https://code.videolan.org/videolan/VLCKit/issues/159#note_12950). I'll have to manually edit VLCMediaPlayer.m to change the UpdateSystemActivity() behavior. I'll post here the result of my attempt, just in case it will be helpful to others in the future. Thanks again for all your support!